# Why Was My Question Closed After Being Migrated from Stack Exchange Law to Here

Tags: support

Yesterday, I asked a [**`question`**](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/159235/collaboration-on-a-financial-project-as-a-backend-developer-with-trust-challenge?noredirect=1#comment328600_159235) on Personal Finance & Money, but it was closed because it was off-topic. Then, I decided to post the same question on Stack Exchange Law, where it was [**`migrated`**](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/159243/guidance-on-documentation-for-cross-border-collaboration-in-financial-project-de) back to Personal Finance & Money and marked as a duplicate. Can you please explain to us why the initial question isn't open, given that someone from Stack Exchange Law migrated it here? I believe it should be open, respectfully.

Answer (score 3):

The first question was closed because it was off topic. I agree with this.

The 2nd question you submitted to Stack exchange law.

They decided two things:

- it was off topic for them (I have no idea if that is the correct decision, but that is what they did)
- They thought it might apply to this site. So they migrated it.

Here it was decided that again it was off topic and now it is a duplicate. I was about to vote it was off topic when the duplicate label was attached to the question.

Not all questions fit into the stack exchange model. Additionally some questions don't fit into the topic areas covered by a particular site.

Comment: As the person who did all the closing on money, this exactly reflects my thinking.